# Deserialize inmutable entity without modifying it

Tags: java, json, jaxb, immutability

Is there any way to define a deserialization mechanism to instantiate a class with all final fields?

Is it possible to use a Builder to achieve this? I would like to avoid modifying this entity (Adding annotations, etc.)

Comment: Can you make more specific ?

Comment: Did u tried java reflection?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JSON take a look at Jackson's `@JsonCreator`. It lets you specify how to construct the object see the [jackson docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations)

If you don't want to annotate your class you can use a mixin to pick up the annotations from a different class. Something a bit like.

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(MyClass.class, MyAnnotations.class)
```